# Modular representations of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ from Steinberg tensor product theorem

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

How to get all the irreducible $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$-representations of ${\rm GL_2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ from Steinberg tensor product theorem? I think one gets the irreducible $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$-representations of ${\rm SL_2}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ from Steinberg tensor product theorem. But how to lift it to the irreducible $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$-representations of ${\rm GL_2}(\mathbb{F}_q).$

Comment: Once you have the irreps for the special one, you just need to twist by suitable powers of the determinant. Steinberg is not required there.